# Place "see also" after page numbers in index

Tags: indexing

I'm creating an index using makeidx. When I have a "see also" cross-reference in an entry, I want it to appear *after* the listing of page numbers. But instead it appears *before* the listing.

Here's what the output currently looks like:

> quantifiers  *see also* numbers, cardinal, 2

Here's what I want the output to look like:

> quantifiers  2, *see also* numbers, cardinal

Is there a straightforward way to change this behavior, say, in my index style file?

Comment: Given that the output is supposed to be the latter, based on what indexing professionals do, I'm sort of surprised that isn't the default.

Answer (score 10):

The order is controlled by the page number. The feature "see" is implemented as encapsulating command:

```
\index{quantifiers|textbf}% bold page number
\index{quantifiers|see{numbers, cardinal}}%
```

Makeindex appends the page number, thus the following macro is called in `\printindex`:

```
\textbf{1} and \see{numbers, cardinal}{1}
```

The implementation of `\see` ignores the page number, but Makeindex sorts the page numbers. With them, the page numbers and see statements are sorted.

The following example defines `\indexsee{<index entry>}{<see entry>}` that writes the index entry with a quite large page number to sort it at the end.
Also the page number is increased each time to avoid warnings of Makeindex, if it sees different encapsulating commands for the same entry.

Macro `\index` reads it argument in verbatim mode. Therefore `\indexsee` should do the same to avoid different outcome of the same index keys (more less spaces, expansion, ...).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\indexsee}{%
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
  \@sanitize
  \@wrindexsee
}
\newcommand*{\@wrindexsee}[2]{%
  \stepcounter{indexsee@page}%
  \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
    \string\indexentry{#1|see{#2}}{\the\value{indexsee@page}}%
  }%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
}
\newcounter{indexsee@page}
\setcounter{indexsee@page}{10000}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Hello
\index{numbers, cardinal}
\index{numbers, funny}
\indexsee{quantifiers}{numbers, funny}
\newpage
World
\index{quantifiers}
\newpage
\null
\indexsee{quantifiers}{numbers, cardinal}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

File `test.idx`, written by the LaTeX run:

```
\indexentry{numbers, cardinal}{1}
\indexentry{numbers, funny}{1}
\indexentry{quantifiers|see{numbers, funny}}{10001}
\indexentry{quantifiers}{2}
\indexentry{quantifiers|see{numbers, cardinal}}{10002}
```

File `test.ind`, generated by Makeindex:

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item numbers, cardinal, 1
  \item numbers, funny, 1

  \indexspace

  \item quantifiers, 2, \see{numbers, funny}{10001}, 
                \see{numbers, cardinal}{10002}

\end{theindex}
```

Comment: I have to remark that the book "Indexing for Editors and Authors" by the American Society of Indexers (yes! there is such a thing!) specifically says "A see reference will never have locators."   But I presume your solution would work with some modification for seealso?

Answer (score 4):

We could use [Xindy](http://www.xindy.org/) for this task, the order of location classes is in our favor and can be used right away. We run some LaTeX engine, e.g.:

> lualatex mal-xindy-see.tex
>   xindy -M texindy -L general -C utf8 mal-xindy-see.idx
>   lualatex mal-xindy-see.tex

```
% run: *latex mal-xindy-see.tex
% xindy -M texindy -L general -C utf8 mal-xindy-see.idx
% and *latex again
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Text before.
\index{numbers, cardinal}
\index{numbers, funny}
\newpage
\index{quantifiers}
\index{quantifiers|see{numbers, funny}}
\index{quantifiers|see{numbers, cardinal}}
Text after.
\begingroup
\def\thispagestyle#1{}
\printindex
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]