# Hyperref shifts location of "see" and "see also" in index. How to restore?

Tags: hyperref, indexing

Unlike the very similar [Place “see also” after page numbers in index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173320/place-see-also-after-page-numbers-in-index) question, this question differs in that it (and any solution) relates to indexing in conjunction with `hyperref`.

With the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  foo\index{foo}\index{foo|seealso{bar}}
  foo\index{foo}
  bar\index{bar}
  \printindex
\end{document}
```

Index page output without the `\usepackage{hyperref}` line is:

```
Index
bar, 1
foo, 1, see also bar
```

The last output line correctly sees the pageno located *before* the *see also* reference.

However, index page output including the `\usepackage{hyperref}` line incorrectly / undesirably relocates the *see also* reference *before* the pageno:

```
Index
bar, 1
foo, see also bar, 1
```

**Question**: how can I have my cake and eat it too, i.e., include `hyperref` but locate pageno references before *see* and *see also* index entry text as in the output without `hyperref`?

[Not a xindy question]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a clue to what's happening in the `makeindex` log file, which contains the warning:

```
## Warning (input = test.idx, line = 2; output = test.ind, line = 7):
   -- Conflicting entries: multiple encaps for the same page under same key.
```

This occurs when an entry is indexed multiple times on the same page with different encaps (the command that encapsulates the page number). Here's an example that illustrates this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\zzz}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\aaa}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
foo\index{foo|textbf}
\index{foo|zzz}
\index{foo|emph}
\index{foo|aaa}
\index{foo}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

This results in four multiple encap warnings. The `ind` file contains:

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item foo, 1, \aaa{1}, \emph{1}, \textbf{1}, \zzz{1}

\end{theindex}
```

`makeindex` has listed each of the five `foo` entries for page one, but has sorted them in the order: no encap (`\index{foo}`) followed by the remaining entries that have been ordered alphabetically according to the encap value.

Now back to your MWE without `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
  foo\index{foo}\index{foo|seealso{bar}}
  foo\index{foo}
  bar\index{bar}
  \printindex
\end{document}
```

Here the first and third `foo` index don't have an encap (`\index{foo}`), so `makeindex` can combine them into an unencapsulated entry for page 1, but the second `foo` index has an encap (`\index{foo|seealso{bar}}`). The encap value being `seealso{bar}`, so the `.ind` file contains the line:

```
  \item foo, 1, \seealso{bar}{1}
```

Again, the entry without an encap is listed first. Now let's add `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  foo\index{foo}\index{foo|seealso{bar}}
  foo\index{foo}
  bar\index{bar}
  \printindex
\end{document}
```

When `hyperref` is added, `hyperref` adds an encap to `\index{foo}` behind the scenes. You can see this by inspecting the `.idx` file, which contains:

```
\indexentry{foo|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{foo|hyperindexformat{\seealso{bar}}}{1}
\indexentry{foo|hyperpage}{1}
```

Again there's a multiple encaps warning and `makeindex` again sorts the conflicting entries alphabetically according the encap, so the `.ind` file now contains:

```
\item foo, \hyperindexformat{\seealso{bar}}{1}, \hyperpage{1}
```

This is what's causing the change in order. The simplest solution is to avoid the multiple encap clash by moving the cross-referenced entries to another part of the document that has a different page number. (Since `\seealso` ignores its second argument, the actual page number is irrelevant.) For example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  foo\index{foo}
  foo\index{foo}
  bar\index{bar}

  \clearpage
  \index{foo|seealso{bar}}
  \printindex
\end{document}
```

This gets rid of the warning and moves the cross-reference to the end of the location list.

[image: image of result]

*Edit:* Another possibility is to switch off `hyperref`'s `hyperindex` option and create a `makeindex` style file to wrap the location list in a command that can add hyperlinks to the page numbers. For example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[hyperindex=false]{hyperref}

\makeindex

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.ist}
delim_0 ", \\locationlist\{"
delim_1 ", \\locationlist\{"
delim_2 ", \\locationlist\{"
delim_t "\}"
delim_n ","
encap_prefix "\\encap\{\\"
encap_infix "\{"
encap_suffix "\}\}"
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\encap}[1]{#1}

\def\@location#1#2\end@location{%
  \ifx\encap#1\relax
    #2%
  \else
    \hyperpage{#1#2}%
  \fi
}

\newcommand*{\locationlist}[1]{%
 \def\locationsep{}%
 \@for\location:=#1\do{%
   \locationsep
   \expandafter\@location\location\end@location
   \def\locationsep{, }%
 }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  foo\index{foo}\index{foo|seealso{bar}}
  foo\index{foo}
  bar\index{bar}

  \clearpage
  bar\index{bar}

  \clearpage
  bar\index{bar}

  \printindex
\end{document}
```

If the file is called `test.tex`, then this needs:

```
pdflatex test
makeindex -s test.ist -o test.ind test.idx
pdflatex test
```

[image: image of index]

This applies `\hyperpage` to the plain locations but not to the encaps. If you have other encaps (for example, `\index{foo|textbf}`) you'll need a wrapper command, for example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[hyperindex=false]{hyperref}

\makeindex

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.ist}
delim_0 ", \\locationlist\{"
delim_1 ", \\locationlist\{"
delim_2 ", \\locationlist\{"
delim_t "\}"
delim_n ","
encap_prefix "\\encap\{\\"
encap_infix "\{"
encap_suffix "\}\}"
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\encap}[1]{#1}

\def\@location#1#2\end@location{%
  \ifx\encap#1\relax
    #2%
  \else
    \hyperpage{#1#2}%
  \fi
}

\newcommand*{\locationlist}[1]{%
 \def\locationsep{}%
 \@for\location:=#1\do{%
   \locationsep
   \expandafter\@location\location\end@location
   \def\locationsep{, }%
 }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\primaryidx}[1]{\textbf{\hyperpage{#1}}}

\begin{document}
  foo\index{foo}\index{foo|seealso{bar}}
  foo\index{foo}
  bar\index{bar}

  \clearpage
  bar\index{bar}

  \clearpage
  bar\index{bar}
  foo\index{foo|primaryidx}

  \printindex
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of index]

Note that the "see also" part isn't at the end of the list as it's associated with page 1. (The analogous `see` key in `glossaries` fakes page `Z` to counteract this issue.) This problem will also occur without `hyperref`.

One way to get around this (if you don't want to move your `\index` commands to the end of the document) is to modify the location parser so that it saves the cross-reference and moves it to the end of the list:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[hyperindex=false]{hyperref}

\makeindex

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.ist}
delim_0 ", \\locationlist\{"
delim_1 ", \\locationlist\{"
delim_2 ", \\locationlist\{"
delim_t "\}"
delim_n ","
encap_prefix "\\encap\{\\"
encap_infix "\{"
encap_suffix "\}\}"
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\encap}[1]{#1}

\def\@ifseealso#1#2\end@ifseealso#3#4{%
  \ifx\seealso#1\relax
   #3%
  \else
   #4%
  \fi
}

\def\@location#1#2\end@location{%
  \ifx\encap#1\relax
    \@ifseealso#2\relax\end@ifseealso
    {\def\crossref{\locationsep #2}}
    {\locationsep #2}%
  \else
    \locationsep
    \hyperpage{#1#2}%
  \fi
}

\newcommand*{\locationlist}[1]{%
 \def\locationsep{}%
 \def\crossref{}%
 \@for\location:=#1\do{%
   \expandafter\@location\location\end@location
   \def\locationsep{, }%
 }%
 \crossref
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\primaryidx}[1]{\textbf{\hyperpage{#1}}}

\begin{document}
  foo\index{foo}\index{foo|seealso{bar}}
  foo\index{foo}
  bar\index{bar}

  \clearpage
  bar\index{bar}

  \clearpage
  bar\index{bar}
  foo\index{foo|primaryidx}

  \printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: image of index]

Comment: Nicola, great forensics -- I learned something new. Not certain that it answers my question, since rather than an over-and-again text-rearranging method I was looking for a programmatic solution to resolve the matter once and for all. Still, I'm marking the question answered since I suspect little better can be done (@Heiko, please add your advice if you think otherwise).

Comment: @Kilgore I've updated my answer if you don't want to rearrange the `\index` commands.